# Paging ListViews in a MultiView control

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I use a MultiView control to display different set of data. on each of the first two Views I have a ListView. When I page the second ListView, the page reloads with the new set of data but I am redirected to the first. It is good to note that the paging of the second view works well, the only problem is that I want to be remain ON the second View after the data is loaded. Any idea on how I can solve this issue?
here is my code:
'''

```
 <asp:MultiView ID="RoutesMultiView" runat="server" ActiveViewIndex="0">
                <asp:View ID="RouteA_View" runat="server">
                    <fieldset class="form-horizontal">
                        <div class="RouteStyle">
                            <asp:ListView ID="RouteAListView" runat="server" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1">
                                <AlternatingItemTemplate>
                                    <tr style="background-color: #E9E9E9; color: black;" class="cellPad">
                                        <td> <%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1%> </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("Pin") %>' runat="server" ID="PinLabel"/></td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("Community") %>' runat="server" ID="CommunityLabel"/></td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("Neighbourhood") %>' runat="server" ID="NeighbourhoodLabel"/></td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("Address") %>' runat="server" ID="AddressLabel"/></td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("Area") %>' runat="server" ID="AreaLabel"/></td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("Notes") %>' runat="server" ID="NotesLabel"/></td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("Cycle1", "{0:MMM-dd}") %>' runat="server" ID="Cycle1Label"/></td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("Cycle2", "{0:MMM-dd}") %>' runat="server" ID="Cycle2Label"/></td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("Cycle3", "{0:MMM-dd}") %>' runat="server" ID="Cycle3Label"/></td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("Cycle4", "{0:MMM-dd}") %>' runat="server" ID="Cycle4Label"/></td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("Cycle5", "{0:MMM-dd}") %>' runat="server" ID="Cycle5Label"/></td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("Pruning", "{0:MMM-dd}") %>' runat="server" ID="PruningLabel"/></td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("Mulching", "{0:MMM-dd}") %>' runat="server" ID="MulchingLabel"/></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </AlternatingItemTemplate>

                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <tr style="background-color: #FFFFFF; color: black;" class="cellPad">
                                        <td> <%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1%> </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("Pin") %>' runat="server" ID="PinLabel"/></td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("Community") %>' runat="server" ID="CommunityLabel"/></td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("Neighbourhood") %>' runat="server" ID="NeighbourhoodLabel"/></td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("Address") %>' runat="server" ID="AddressLabel"/></td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("Area") %>' runat="server" ID="AreaLabel"/></td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("Notes") %>' runat="server" ID="NotesLabel"/></td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("Cycle1", "{0:MMM-dd}") %>' runat="server" ID="Cycle1Label"/></td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("Cycle2", "{0:MMM-dd}") %>' runat="server" ID="Cycle2Label"/></td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("Cycle3", "{0:MMM-dd}") %>' runat="server" ID="Cycle3Label"/></td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("Cycle4", "{0:MMM-dd}") %>' runat="server" ID="Cycle4Label"/></td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("Cycle5", "{0:MMM-dd}") %>' runat="server" ID="Cycle5Label"/></td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("Pruning", "{0:MMM-dd}") %>' runat="server" ID="PruningLabel"/></td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("Mulching", "{0:MMM-dd}") %>' runat="server" ID="MulchingLabel"/></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <LayoutTemplate>
                                    <table runat="server">
                                        <tr runat="server">
                                            <td runat="server">
                                                <table runat="server" id="itemPlaceholderContainer" style="background-color: #FFFFFF; border-collapse: collapse; border-color: #999999; border-style: none; font-weight: normal; border-width: 1px; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;" border="1">
                                                    <tr runat="server" style="background-color: #DCDCDC; color: black;" class="routeListviewHeader">
                                                        <th runat="server" style="width:5px"></th>
                                                        <th runat="server" style="text-align: center; width: 70px;">Pin</th>
                                                        <th runat="server" style="text-align: center; width: 100px;">Community</th>
                                                        <th runat="server" style="text-align: center; width: 150px;">Neighbourhood</th>
                                                        <th runat="server" style="text-align: center; width: 200px;">Address</th>
                                                        <th runat="server" style="text-align: center; width: 50px;">Area</th>
                                                        <th runat="server" style="text-align: center; width: 300px;">Notes</th>
                                                        <th runat="server" class="cycleHeader">Cycle 1</th>
                                                        <th runat="server" class="cycleHeader">Cycle 2</th>
                                                        <th runat="server" class="cycleHeader">Cycle 3</th>
                                                        <th runat="server" class="cycleHeader">Cycle 4</th>
                                                        <th runat="server" class="cycleHeader">Cycle 5</th>
                                                        <th runat="server" style="text-align: center; width: 75px;">Pruning</th>
                                                        <th runat="server" style="text-align: center; width: 80px;">Mulching</th>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder"></tr>
                                                </table>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr runat="server">
                                            <td runat="server" style="text-align: center; background-color: white; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: black">
                                                <asp:DataPager runat="server" ID="RouteA_DataPager" PageSize="10" PagedControlID="RouteAListView"  QueryStringField="ARoutePage">
                                                    <Fields>
                                                        <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Button" ShowFirstPageButton="True" ShowLastPageButton="True"></asp:NextPreviousPagerField>
                                                    </Fields>
                                                </asp:DataPager>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </LayoutTemplate>
                            </asp:ListView>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                </asp:View>
                <asp:View ID="RouteB_View" runat="server">
                   <fieldset class="form-horizontal">
                       <div class="RouteStyle">
                           <asp:ListView ID="RouteBListView" runat="server" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1">
                                <AlternatingItemTemplate>
                                    <tr style="background-color: #E9E9E9; color: black;" class="cellPad">
                                        <td><%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1%> </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("Pin") %>' runat="server" ID="PinLabel" CssClass=" routeCell" /></td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("Community") %>' runat="server" ID="CommunityLabel" CssClass=" routeCell" /></td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("Neighbourhood") %>' runat="server" ID="NeighbourhoodLabel" CssClass=" routeCell" /></td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("Address") %>' runat="server" ID="AddressLabel" CssClass=" routeCell" /></td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("Area") %>' runat="server" ID="AreaLabel" CssClass=" routeCell" /></td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("Notes") %>' runat="server" ID="NotesLabel" CssClass=" routeCell" /></td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("Cycle1", "{0:MMM-dd}") %>' runat="server" ID="Cycle1Label" CssClass=" routeCell" /></td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("Cycle2", "{0:MMM-dd}") %>' runat="server" ID="Cycle2Label" CssClass=" routeCell" /></td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("Pruning", "{0:MMM-dd}") %>' runat="server" ID="PruningLabel" CssClass=" routeCell" /></td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("Mulching", "{0:MMM-dd}") %>' runat="server" ID="MulchingLabel" CssClass=" routeCell" /></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </AlternatingItemTemplate>
                               <EmptyDataTemplate>
                                   <table runat="server" style="background-color: #FFFFFF; border-collapse: collapse; border-color: #999999; border-style: none; border-width: 1px;">
                                       <tr>
                                           <td><span style="color: firebrick;">No Data Returned</span></td>
                                       </tr>
                                   </table>
                               </EmptyDataTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <tr style="background-color: #FFFFFF; color: black;" class="cellPad">
                                        <td><%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1%> </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("Pin") %>' runat="server" ID="PinLabel" CssClass="routePin routeCell" /></td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("Community") %>' runat="server" ID="CommunityLabel" CssClass=" routeCell" /></td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("Neighbourhood") %>' runat="server" ID="NeighbourhoodLabel" CssClass=" routeCell" /></td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("Address") %>' runat="server" ID="AddressLabel" CssClass=" routeCell" /></td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("Area") %>' runat="server" ID="AreaLabel" CssClass=" routeCell" /></td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("Notes") %>' runat="server" ID="NotesLabel" CssClass="routeCell" /></td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("Cycle1", "{0:MMM-dd}") %>' runat="server" ID="Cycle1Label" CssClass=" routeCell" /></td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("Cycle2", "{0:MMM-dd}") %>' runat="server" ID="Cycle2Label" CssClass=" routeCell" /></td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("Pruning", "{0:MMM-dd}") %>' runat="server" ID="PruningLabel" CssClass=" routeCell" /></td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("Mulching", "{0:MMM-dd}") %>' runat="server" ID="MulchingLabel" CssClass=" routeCell" /></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <LayoutTemplate>
                                    <table runat="server">
                                        <tr runat="server">
                                            <td runat="server">
                                                <table runat="server" id="itemPlaceholderContainer" style="background-color: #FFFFFF; border-collapse: collapse; border-color: #999999; border-style: none; font-weight: normal; border-width: 1px; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;" border="1">
                                                    <tr runat="server" style="background-color: #DCDCDC; color: black;" class="routeListviewHeader">
                                                        <th runat="server" style="width:5px"></th>
                                                        <th runat="server" style="text-align: center; width: 70px;">Pin</th>
                                                        <th runat="server" style="text-align: center; width: 100px;">Community</th>
                                                        <th runat="server" style="text-align: center; width: 150px;">Neighbourhood</th>
                                                        <th runat="server" style="text-align: center; width: 200px;">Address</th>
                                                        <th runat="server" style="text-align: center; width: 50px;">Area</th>
                                                        <th runat="server" style="text-align: center; width: 300px;">Notes</th>
                                                        <th runat="server" class="cycleHeader">Cycle 1</th>
                                                        <th runat="server" class="cycleHeader">Cycle 2</th>
                                                        <th runat="server" style="text-align: center; width: 75px;">Pruning</th>
                                                        <th runat="server" style="text-align: center; width: 80px;">Mulching</th>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder"></tr>
                                                </table>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr runat="server">
                                            <td runat="server" style="text-align: center; background-color: white; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: black">
                                                <asp:DataPager ID="RouteB_DataPager" runat="server" PageSize="20" PagedControlID="RouteBListView" QueryStringField="BRoutePage">
                                                    <Fields>
                                                        <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Button" ShowFirstPageButton="True" ShowLastPageButton="True"></asp:NextPreviousPagerField>
                                                    </Fields>
                                                </asp:DataPager>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </LayoutTemplate>
                            </asp:ListView>
                        </div>
                   </fieldset>
                </asp:View>
  </asp:MultiView>
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

The issue was on the PostBack. Each time I was paging the second View, the page was reloading from start. I just needed to check the PostBack from the code behind and not allowing the page to load with the strating settings